# Como controlar leitura de arquivo txt

Tags: c++

Possuo a seguinte entrada em um arquivo `.txt`:

```
var a;
var b; var c;
a = (10+2)/2;
b = a*2;
c = a*b;
print a; print b; print c;
```

Onde a função getToken() irá  me retornar o token atual, contendo o tipo e seu valor. Por exemplo:

1º chamada do método `getToken()`:
irá retornar um objeto do tipo `Token`, contendo **palavraChave**  e **var**

2ª chamada do método `getToken()`:
irá retornar um objeto do tipo `Token`, contendo **ID** e **a**

3ª chamada do método `getToken()`:
irá retornar um objeto do tipo `Token`, contendo **delimitador** e **;**

e assim por diante.

Ou seja, preciso analisar o arquivo de tal forma que seja possível controlar onde peguei o ultimo *token*. O código abaixo é inviável, pois não consigo controlar em qual parte do arquivo capturei o último símbolo:

```
if(entrada.is_open()){
    while(getline(entrada, linha)){
        int tam_linha = linha.size();
        for(int i=0; i<=tam_linha-1; i++){
        }
    }
}
```

Sendo assim,  como faço para que ao chamar a função `getToken()`, o arquivo seja lido de maneira "interrupta" e me retorne o próximo simbolo?

Apêndice:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não faça isto. Leia o arquivo e analise depois.

Comment: Como  seria feita essa leitura? Teria que armazenar toda  entrada em algum vetor ou algo do tipo? @Maniero

Comment: Pode ser em vetor uma uma *string* mesmo.